# Проверка на валидность или заполнено ли поле

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите что вставить чтобы проверяла заполнено ли поле? а то отправляет пустые из сафари и IE. Вот код скрипта

```
 $(function(){
        /* Mail */
        $('.mail').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).children('.send').replaceWith("<h5 class='nomargbut'>Спасибо за заявку!</h5><h5 class='nomargbut'>Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение 30 минут</h5>");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sends.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "true"){
                        $('.back, .hide').hide().before('<div class="success">Спасибо за заявку! Мы свяжемся с Вами в течение дня.</div>');
                        setTimeout("$('.success').fadeOut()", 3000);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Так на валидность проверка или на пустоту? Если на пустоту, то что вам мешает?

    $('.mail').submit(e){
        if($.trim($('mail_field_selector').val()) === '') return false;
        // ...

На валидность проверить мыло - тогда еще и регуляркоы по нему пробежаться.

Comment: Благодарствую от всей души!Спасибо!!!

Comment: А как сделать на валидность? Вот этого?
<input id="phone" maxlength="20" name="phone" type="text" placeholder='Введите телефон' pattern='8[0-9]{10}' required title="Формат (с цифры 8 и без пробелов): 89061111111" class="placeholder">

Comment: @Александр Дахно зачем вы `[закрыт]` приделываете к своим вопросам ? это совсем другое значит. Если вопрос имеет ответ, то помечайте его галкой, если нет, но есть коммент помогший, попросите превратить коммент в ответ, это многие могут сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот две простых проверки, одна на пустое поле другая на `Email`

```
var name = document.myFormName.name.value,
    email = document.myFormName.email.value;

if (name.length <= 1 || (!(/^\w+[-_\.]*\w+@\w+-?\w+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/.test(email)))) {
    // Проверяем сразу два поля
    // И добавляем им класс ошибки
    $(".name, .email").addClass("alert");

    // А потом можно проверить каждое отдельно
    if(name.length > 1) {
      $('.name').removeClass('alert');
    }

    if ((/^\w+[-_\.]*\w+@\w+-?\w+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/.test(email))) {
      $('.email').removeClass('alert');
    }
    return false;
} else {
    $(".name, .email").removeClass("alert");

    // И тут ваш Ajax запрос
}
```

Comment: Таким образом мы будем выбирать отдельное не заполненное поле из всего списка, то есть если пользователь заполнил из 3 полей только 2-е, то ошибка покажется на первом и третьем.